# HTML-Only Form Submit

Tags: html, http

How do I create a form that can submit a value to another page and then print it out without using any server-side code from a programming language?

i.e. **First.html**

```
<form method="get" action="Second.html">
  <input type="text" name="myname" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Second.html**

```
<p>input.myname</p>
```

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript, otherwise it's impossible, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do it that way, and actually i don't see any advantage.

Anyway, in second.html, you could use javascript (jquery framework for example) to parse query string and get your value back.

**first.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="second.html">
        <input type="text" name="myname" />
        <input type="submit" value="click me" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, in your **second.html**, use this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Test: ' + $.QueryString["myname"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to transfer data from one page to another without using a server-side code ? That's extremely unrecommended, it can be used using javascript like Justin said, I'd recommend you ASP.NET and passing with `QueryString` or `Session` as you can see in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Your other answer couldn't be undeleted, because the question it was on needed to be removed, but I've undeleted this one to give you a chance to edit it into something more substantial. This should clear the answering block on your account.